# Setting UIToolBar Background image swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitoolbar, uibarmetrics, uitoolbarposition

I am using swift to make an IOS application. I have a `UIToolBar` in my application and I need to change its background. I use the following code in Objective-C to do that:

```
[topBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_bg.png"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Now when I rewrote the code in swift it looks like this:

```
topBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"header_bg.png"), forToolbarPosition: UIToolbarPositionAny, barMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault)
```

And this showed the errors that `Use of unresolved type UIBarMetricsDefault` and `Use of unresolved type UIToolbarPositionAny`. So I did a search and found [**this**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarPositioning_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarPosition) documentation. According to the documentation I changed the code like this:

```
topBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"header_bg.png"), forToolbarPosition: Any, barMetrics: Default)
```

But it still shows the same error. Anyone got any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enums are done a little differently in Swift. For example, instead of saying: `UIBarMetricsDefault`, you say `.Default`. So, your code should look like this:

```
topBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"header_bg.png"), forToolbarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)
```

I recommend you look at the "Introduction to Swift" document on http://developer.apple.com for more info on how to write / use enums.

Comment: Exactly.. You said it.. :D